# escape a string which contains non-ascii

Tags: python, escaping

now I have string s = "\\u653e"

I want to convert this string into s = "\u653e"

I try to make it clear:

```
# this is what I want
>>s
>>'\u653e'
# this is not what I want, print will escape the string automatically 
>>print s
>>\653e
```

how can I do that?

---

the original question is that

I have a string s = u'\u653e', [s] = [u'\u653e']
So I want to remove the u, that is, [s] = ['\u653e']

so I just use the command ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(r)) to get the above string "\\u653e"

---

**UPDATE**
Thanks tdelaney

Creating a string from an entire list causes my problem. What I should to do is using a unicode string to start with and build the list from its individual elements instead of the entire list.  For more details you can see his answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've said that you want to convert `"\u653e"` into `"\u653e"`; they're both the same thing! Please make your question clearer so that you get better answers.

Comment: To clarify... `u'\u653e'` is a single unicode character and `print s` results in `放`. You want its 6 character literal string representation `'\u653e'`?

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 sorry, the editer automatically escape the string I typed, now it's clear

Comment: @tdelaney Yes :) Because I want to insert '\u653e' into Orientdb

Comment: I don't know Orientdb or your particular circumstances, but doesn't it handle unicode strings? You are un-unicode-izing it (to coin a phrase) but I'm not sure that's necessary.

Comment: @tdelaney I read data from a excel file. So I get a array like this s = [u'一', u'二', u'三']  so when I construct the sql command, I get a string like this: create vertex v set s = [u'\u4e00', u'\u4e8c', u'\u4e09'] but orientdb can only parse '\u4e00' rather u'\u4e00' that's why I want to do a ununicode-izing :)

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you are creating the command string. Can you post how you do that? An example starting from `s = [u'一', u'二', u'三']` is find.  I'll update my answer with a guess on how you can get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a single unicode character. `"\u653e` is a literal encoding that python uses to express unicode characters in ascii text. The `unicode_escape` codec converts between these types.

```
>>> s = u'\u653e'
>>> print type(s), len(s), s
<type 'unicode'> 1 放
>>> encoded = s.encode('unicode_escape')
>>> print type(encoded), len(encoded), encoded
<type 'str'> 6 \u653e
```

In your example just do

```
s = u'\u653e'
somelist = [s.encode('unicode_escape')]
>>> print somelist
['\\u653e']
>>> print somelist[0]
\u653e
```

**update**

From your comments, your problem may be how you create your command string. There seems to be a problem with the python representation of a string verses the string itself. Use a unicode string to start with and build the list from its individual elements instead of the entire list.

```
>>> excel = [u'\u4e00', u'\u4e8c', u'\u4e09']
>>> cmd = u'create vertex v set s = [{}]'.format(u','.join(excel))
>>> cmd
u'create vertex v set s = [\u4e00,\u4e8c,\u4e09]'
>>> print cmd
create vertex v set s = [一,二,三]
```

Comment: thanxs for your answer. But your method exactually remove the u character, but somelist = ['\\u653e'], it still has two blackslash . What I want is >> somelist  >> ['\u653e']  not >> print somelist[0] >> \u653e

Comment: I updated the example to print the python representation of `somelist` and its printed value because I'm not sure which view of the string we are talking about. If you want the exact text `\u653e` it will look like `'\\u653e'` when you print its python string representation because python has to escape the `\ ` to show that it really is a `\ ` and not just a modifier for the following `u`.

Comment: cool. The update is what I want, thanks for your patience. :)